# If a solution differential equation is constant on a interval then it is constant everywhere

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a solution to a differential equation that is constant on some interval will it be constant everywhere?

How does one proof this if this is the case?

Comment: I believe the statement that you're going for is if $y'=f(y)$ and $f$ is locally Lipschitz then a solution which is constant on an interval is constant everywhere. With just the autonomousness assumption this doesn't hold, as Hans showed. And without the autonomousness assumption this is just a complete non-starter, as Darsen showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't need to be the case.

Consider the differential equation: $y'=f(t,y)$, where $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ is defined as follows

$f(t,y)=\begin{cases}2t&\text{if }t\ge0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

We have that $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb R^2$, so the ODE is perfectly valid.

Then for every $a\in\Bbb R$ we have a solution, which would be the function $\phi(t)=\begin{cases}t^2+a&\text{if }t\ge0\\a&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$, since

$\phi'(t)=\begin{cases}2t&\text{if }t\ge0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 2):

No, for example the function defined by $y(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$ and $y(x) = x^2$ for $x>0$ satisfies the ODE $y'(x) = 2 \sqrt{|y(x)|}$ for all $x$ (including $x=0$).